# Checking if SalesforceInteractions has been initialized

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, personalization

I'm attempting call to `SalesforceInteractions.sendEvent` outside of the `init` function's `promise` resolution.  I would like to be able to check to make sure the object has been initialized before attempting to use it.  Something like this:

```
// normal init code
SalesforceInteractions.init({
    trackerUrl: "https://somewhere.us-6.evergage.com",
    cookieDomain: "somewhere.org"
}).then(() => { 
    // page type config, etc.
});

const mySendEvent = () => {
    if (SalesforceInteractions.isInitialized) {
        SalesforceInteractions.sendEvent({
            interaction: {
                name: 'Did something',
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if something like this exists?  Alternatively, does anyone know if calling `SalesforceInteractions.init()` more than once is problematic?  Finally, is there any thorough documentation of the `SalesforceInteractions` API?